# Rails Tutorial 3 Chapter 7: User Model Rspec Test Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following the Rails Tutorial 3 successfully until I got to chapter 7 and implemented the user model, now my rspec keeps failing.

Here's my user.rb file output

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessible :name, :email

email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

validates :name,     :presence => true,
                     :length   => { :maximum => 50 }

validates :email,    :presence   => true,
                     :format     => { :with => email_regex },
                     :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

validates :password, :presence => true,
                     :confirmation => true,
                     :length => { :within => 6..40 }

before_save :encrypt_password

# Return tue if the user's password matches the submitted password.
    def has_password?(submitted_password)
        encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
    end

    def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
        user = find_by_email(email)
        return nil  if user.nil?
        return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
    end

private

def encrypt_password
  self.salt = make_salt unless has_password?(password)
  self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
end

def encrypt(string)
  secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
end

def make_salt
  secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
end

def secure_hash(string)
  Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
end
end
```

Here's my users_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before(:each) do
  @attr = { 
  :name => "Example User",
  :email => "user@example.com",
  :password => "foobar",
  :password_confirmation => "foobar"
    }
  end

  it "should create a new instance given a valid attribute" do
    User.create!(@attr)
  end

  it "should require a name" do
    no_name_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:name => ""))
    no_name_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should require an email address" do
    no_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => ""))
    no_email_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject names that are too long" do
    long_name = "a" * 51
    long_name_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:name => long_name))
    long_name_user.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should accept valid email addresses" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo.com THE_USER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp]
    addresses.each do |address|
      valid_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => address))
      valid_email_user.should be_valid
    end
  end

  it "should reject invalid email addresses" do
    addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.]
    addresses.each do |address|
      invalid_email_user = User.new(@attr.merge(:email => address))
      invalid_email_user.should_not be_valid
    end
   end

  it "should reject duplicate email addresses" do
    User.create!(@attr)
    user_with_duplicate_email = User.new(@attr)
    user_with_duplicate_email.should_not be_valid
  end

  it "should reject email addresses identical up to case" do
    upcased_email = @attr[:email].upcase
    User.create!(@attr.merge(:email => upcased_email))
    user_with_duplicate_email = User.new(@attr)
    user_with_duplicate_email.should_not be_valid
  end

  describe "passwords" do

before(:each) do
      @user = User.create!(@attr)
    end

    it "should have a password attribute" do
      @user.should respond_to(:password)
    end

it "should have a password confirmation attribute" do
  @user.should respond_to(:password_confirmation)
end
  end

      describe "password validations" do

    it "should require a password" do
      User.new(@attr.merge(:password => "", :password_confirmation => "")).
        should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should require a matching password confirmation" do
      User.new(@attr.merge(:password_confirmation => "invalid")).
        should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should reject short passwords" do
      short = "a" * 5
      hash = @attr.merge(:password => short, :password_confirmation => short)
      User.new(hash).should_not be_valid
    end

    it "should reject long passwords" do
      long = "a" * 41
      hash = @attr.merge(:password => long, :password_confirmation => long)
      User.new(hash).should_not be_valid
    end
  end
end
```

Finally here's the output of my rspec

```
Failures:

  1) UsersController GET 'show' should be successfull
 Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
 ArgumentError:
   Factory not registered: user
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user
 Failure/Error: @user = Factory(:user)
 ArgumentError:
   Factory not registered: user
 # ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User should create a new instance given a valid attribute
 Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d3684e0b0>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User should require a name
 Failure/Error: no_name_user.should_not be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d36eacf38>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:20:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User should require an email address
 Failure/Error: no_email_user.should_not be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d36e45978>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:25:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) User should reject names that are too long
 Failure/Error: long_name_user.should_not be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d36e0b2a0>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:31:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) User should accept valid email addresses
 Failure/Error: valid_email_user.should be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d36da4c80>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:38:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:36:in `each'
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:36:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) User should reject invalid email addresses
 Failure/Error: invalid_email_user.should_not be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d36d870b8>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:44:in `each'
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9) User should reject duplicate email addresses
 Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d36c6c890>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  10) User should reject email addresses identical up to case
 Failure/Error: User.create!(@attr.merge(:email => upcased_email))
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d36c4d878>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  11) User passwords should have a password attribute
 Failure/Error: @user = User.create!(@attr)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d36b3cda8>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  12) User passwords should have a password confirmation attribute
 Failure/Error: @user = User.create!(@attr)
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d369c27c0>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:66:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  13) User password validations should require a password
 Failure/Error: User.new(@attr.merge(:password => "", :password_confirmation => "")).
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d3699e5f0>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:81:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  14) User password validations should require a matching password confirmation
 Failure/Error: User.new(@attr.merge(:password_confirmation => "invalid")).
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d3698e600>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:86:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  15) User password validations should reject short passwords
 Failure/Error: User.new(hash).should_not be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d3697dda0>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:93:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  16) User password validations should reject long passwords
 Failure/Error: User.new(hash).should_not be_valid
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `password' for #<User:0x007f9d3696c5a0>
 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:99:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.80301 seconds
35 examples, 16 failures, 2 pending

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:12 # UsersController GET 'show' should be successfull
rspec ./spec/controllers/users_controller_spec.rb:17 # UsersController GET 'show' should find the right user
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:14 # User should create a new instance given a valid attribute
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:18 # User should require a name
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:23 # User should require an email address
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:28 # User should reject names that are too long
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:34 # User should accept valid email addresses
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:42 # User should reject invalid email addresses
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:50 # User should reject duplicate email addresses
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:56 # User should reject email addresses identical up to case
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:69 # User passwords should have a password attribute
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:73 # User passwords should have a password confirmation attribute
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:80 # User password validations should require a password
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:85 # User password validations should require a matching password confirmation
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:90 # User password validations should reject short passwords
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:96 # User password validations should reject long passwords
```

Any ideas on what's going on? I've been stuck on this for about a week now

Comment: Show your users_integration tests, also make sure to run all the migrations and restart the server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have accessible `password` or `password_confirmation` properties on your model. Change:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email
```

to:

```
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Comment: Brilliant, can't believe I missed that :( nice one :) it's still coming up with 14 failures but I think that's because there are no users in the db yet.